# What does to way multi approval transaction?

Tags: web3js, transactions, ether, pancakeswap, swaps

I am going to running swap transactions.
At first, we are going to running an approval transaction.
And then we are going to running a swap transaction.
These repeat.
I made the transaction data.

approval transaction data

```
var data = iface.encodeFunctionData('approve', [config[config.network].addresses.router, ethers.BigNumber.from("115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935")]);
```

swap data....

....

repeat

I hope to have only one running an approval transaction.

for example

```
approval transaction
swap transaction
swap transaction
swap transaction
swap transaction
swap transaction
```

...

Do you have away?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you should be fine since you are already approving the maximum uint. You can just call approve once and you should be able to swap that token as many times as you'd like.

If you want to swap multiple tokens, just approve them all in the same way before you start swapping.

Of course this is slightly less secure than approving only the required amount.

Comment: I know about that.
But if I had depended on this mode, I have a fee for transactions every time.
I have to avoid this fee. I need that approve many transactions only one time.
I'll wait for your reply.

Comment: Each token will require an `approve()` call to it's contract, so if you have 10 tokens to approve, that means you need to pay gas for 10 separate approval transactions. There is no way around this.